# Nested Array Form (Angular2)

Tags: angular, material-design, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

i'am creating nested form array that structured like this
[image]

the form got an error when i want to add array into `objects`

[image]

here is the **[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0SSEQYFFmnH70dBE3sMJ?p=preview)**

if you have difficulty to understand,please tell me.

Comment: Share some code please.

Comment: @MrJSingh i already include the code..here once more
https://plnkr.co/edit/foJsKKa08lgd5KuAghMU?p=preview

Comment: sorry i forgot the plnkr part.

Comment: You need to do nested loop inside the html

Comment: @Vignesh can you elaborate more..i dont understand

Comment: @mayur both `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` already exist in the code..i think the mapping is the causes of the error

Comment: @mayur i had deleted other code that is not involved in this problem

Comment: @deanz the object is not binded properly for surveys object check the below code

Comment: Can you reproduce it in this example? https://plnkr.co/edit/k2neX2DLtCnoDuLzhzvQ?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui  i had edit the example..it can run now, with same error i'm facing

Comment: @yurzui code fixed..go to survey tab and click on Line End Button..the error will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only error you seem to have in your plunker, is the iteration of the `surveys` array, instead of:

```
*ngFor="let survey of myForm.controls.objects.controls; let j=index"
```

it should be:

```
*ngFor="let survey of object.controls.surveys.controls; let j=index"
```

where `object` refers to the iterations of `objects` form array in the higher level iteration.

So now when clicking `Line End` button in the `Survey` tab is working fine, see the forked [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZLlOjsWfG0N6gcqvys1X?p=preview)

Comment: tq..you just save me.

Comment: do you know how to show latest arrayForm and hide the previous one? please help me

Comment: Do you mean to show only the latest object in a form array? Well, I guess you could set an if-statement to only show the last one based on the length of the array, but that would of course hide the others, what if user wants to revisit other form object in that array?

Comment: yes, i want to show only latest objecs as it was requested by user. i had try if-statement but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

See Your code the error states that the surveys object is not binded while looping.You need to loop properly in HTML .Check the below code

```
     <div *ngFor="let item of formvalue.objects; let i=index">
    <ul>
       <li>{{item.date}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div *ngFor="let survey of item.surveys ; let j=index">
    <ul>
      <li>{{survey.br_0}} </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it didn't work..nothing is display..
worked plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/k2neX2DLtCnoDuLzhzvQ?p=preview